# Question regarding double integrals

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, geometric-probability

Regarding the Buffon's needle case for long needles of length $ l>t, $ (the distance between the parallel lines on the floor), we need to solve the integral $$ \int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{x=0}^{m(\theta)}  \frac{4}{t\pi}\,dx\,d\theta $$
where $m(\theta) $ is the minimum between $(l/2)\sin\theta$ and $t/2 $. My question is how do I calculate the integral where the limit is a minimum of two numbers of which either can be greater than the other?

Comment: $t$ and $l$ are constants, so split the double integral into two double integrals.

Comment: @Ritz Thanks, I figured it out. Basically $lsin\theta<t$ for lower values of $\theta$, and after a certain value of $\theta$, $t<lsin\theta$. So I've to find that particular $\theta$ and split the integral there, with $0$ to $\theta$ as the limits of the first one (where $m(\theta)$ is $(l/2)sin\theta$, since it is smaller than $t/2$) and $\theta$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as the limits of the second one (where $t/2$ is the smaller one, since $sin\theta$ increases with $\theta$ and is hence larger).